# A-Frame: Screenshot color management is breaking

Tags: javascript, three.js, screenshot, aframe

Is there some way I can make sure the screenshot capture retains my renderer color management settings?

I have color management set to true (right image), but as soon as I take a screenshot it takes it as if it was false (left image).
[image: screenshot]

I'm just using the basic screen capture code:

```
const scene = document.querySelector('a-scene');
scene.setAttribute('screenshot', {
      width: 4096,
      height: 2048
});
scene.components.screenshot.capture('perspective');
```

Comment: maybe try `Entity.flushToDOM()`? In your case `scene.flushToDOM()` to ensure everything is up to date in DOM before taking screenshot.

Comment: There was an issue recently fixed. You might wanna read https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4841